React Context API one of the object values not retained
I am trying to set my Context API object as below in  one of functional components as below;
I set it 3 times in the same component as below;
    let tmpObj = {
        user1: props.user1,
        user2: props.user2
    }
// Called 2nd. Below is NOT retained
    setMyContextApiObj({
        ...myContextApiObj,
        tmpObj
    });
    
//Called 3rd. This one is retained    
    setMyContextApiObj({
      ...myContextApiObj,
      myValFromStorage: myValFromStorage
    });   
    
//Called 1st. This one is retained    
    setMyContextApiObj({
        ...myContextApiObj,
        myPref: myPref
    }); 

    

However, for some reason, I only get the myValFromStorage and myPref values once I am out of this component and not the tmpObj one.
Not sure why that value is not getting retained in the Context API

Probably a stale closure variable, but we'll need to see more. In particular, what is the code or sequence of code that causes these 3 calls to happen?

Updated with the order of the calls

Are you using multiple setMyContextApiObj calls during the same function/callback/effect? Could you try to using an updater function instead? setMyContextApiObj((myContextApiObj) => ({ ...myContextApiObj, tmpObj })) Do this for all three of the set state invocations, not just for second statement. See: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

@copenndthagen That's not quite the information i was looking for. Are you calling them back to back in a useEffect? 3 different useEffects? a click event handler, a scroll event handler, and a websocket event handler? In the middle of rendering?

You have two options for solving this problem:
1-Make all the desired changes to your context value in a single call to the setMyContextApiObj function. This involves summarizing all the changes into one function call:
 setMyContextApiObj({
        ...myContextApiObj,
        tmpObj, 
        myValFromStorage: myValFromStorage,
        myPref: myPref
    });

2-Instead of explicitly passing an object to the setMyContextApiObj function's input, pass a function to it that returns the new context state value. This way, React will understand that there is a dependency between all the new values and will execute all the calls in order, after the previous call and the previous context value has been set:
        setMyContextApiObj((c) => {
            return {
                ...c, 
                tmpObj
           }
        })
        setMyContextApiObj((c) => {
            return {
                ...c, 
                myValFromStorage: myValFromStorag
            }
        })
        setMyContextApiObj((c) => {
            return {
                ...c, 
                myPref: myPref
            }
        })

this is an example to explain how it work:
codesandbox

Awesome....the 2nd way works....actually i cannot use the 1st option, since the attributes are set in different methods in a way...

I'm happy to hear that your issue was resolved @copenndthagen
